# ASP.NET Core & Angular2 solution not working with Windows Authentication within IIS Express 10

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, windows-authentication, iis-express

I am trying to make Windows Authentication work within an ASP.NET Core & Angular 2 Web application.

The application was created using the following commands:

```
npm install -g yo generator-aspnetcore-spa
yo aspnetcore-spa
```

When accessing the home page which also initializes the SPA, I receive the following error:

```
Exception: Call to Node module failed with error: Response with status: 401 null for URL:

    Microsoft.AspNetCore.NodeServices.HostingModels.HttpNodeInstance+<InvokeExportAsync>d__7.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.NodeServices.HostingModels.OutOfProcessNodeInstance+<InvokeExportAsync>d__14.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.NodeServices.NodeServicesImpl+<InvokeExportWithPossibleRetryAsync>d__10.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.NodeServices.NodeServicesImpl+<InvokeExportWithPossibleRetryAsync>d__10.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Prerendering.PrerenderTagHelper+<ProcessAsync>d__33.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Runtime.TagHelpers.TagHelperRunner+<RunAsync>d__0.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
AspNetCore._Views_Home_Index_cshtml+<ExecuteAsync>d__31.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView+<RenderPageAsync>d__14.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView+<RenderAsync>d__13.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewExecutor+<ExecuteAsync>d__18.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewResult+<ExecuteResultAsync>d__26.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker+<InvokeResultAsync>d__30.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker+<InvokeNextResultFilterAsync>d__28.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ResultExecutedContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(ref State next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker+<InvokeNextResourceFilter>d__22.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(ref State next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker+<InvokeAsync>d__20.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.RouterMiddleware+<Invoke>d__4.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Webpack.ConditionalProxyMiddleware+<Invoke>d__5.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Webpack.ConditionalProxyMiddleware+<Invoke>d__5.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware+<Invoke>d__7.MoveNext()
```

`HomeController`'s Index method is hit and I receive a correct value for `User.Identity`.

My configuration files looks as follows:

**.vs\config\applicationhost.config (IIS Express configuration file)**

```
<authentication>

    <anonymousAuthentication enabled="false" />
    <basicAuthentication enabled="false" />
    <clientCertificateMappingAuthentication enabled="false" />
    <digestAuthentication enabled="false" />

    <iisClientCertificateMappingAuthentication enabled="false">
    </iisClientCertificateMappingAuthentication>

    <windowsAuthentication enabled="true">
        <providers>
          <add value="NTLM" />
          <add value="Negotiate" />
        </providers>
    </windowsAuthentication>

</authentication>

<authorization>
    <add accessType="Allow" users="*" />
</authorization>
```

**web.config** (I do not think it is used when running within IIS Express)

```
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified" />
    </handlers>
    <aspNetCore processPath="%LAUNCHER_PATH%" arguments="%LAUNCHER_ARGS%" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" forwardWindowsAuthToken="true" />
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
  </system.webServer>
```

**launghsettings.json**

```
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": true,
    "anonymousAuthentication": false,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:53968/",
      "sslPort": 0
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
```

The error suggests an access denied, but I do not know how to investigate it. Developer tools does not show any other request except the GET for the initial page.

**Question:** How can I make Windows Authentication within IIS Express when used in conjunction with Angular2?

**Note:** when deploying on IIS, everything works fine.

Comment: Maybe you need to take a look at this first: https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1022870/AngularJS-Web-API-Active-Directory-Security The article is for AngularJS but it should give some ideas.

Comment: @wannadream - yes, I have looked into it and tried to split WebApi and Angular 2 into two Web projects. The WebApi uses Windows Authentication and Angular 2 app allows anonymous access. I do not receive the error, but http calls from Angular 2 still fail (looks like CORS with Windows Authentication related issue). Once I make it work, I will add a response here. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

`wannadream`'s suggestion is a good one, as it helps in having the proper architecture when pairing Angular 2/4 with ASP.NET Core (having an application for delivering SPA and static files and one to for Web API).

I have managed to tackle my problem by removing `asp-prerender-module` attribute from `Home/Index.cshtml`:

```
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home Page";
}

@*asp-prerender-module="ClientApp/dist/main-server"*@
<app>Loading...</app>

<script src="~/dist/vendor.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
@section scripts {
    <script src="~/dist/main-client.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
}
```

However, it is still unclear for me what is the purpose of `asp-prerender-module`, but it does not seem to affect any of the functionality of the application.